# How does ConcurrentHashMap achieve its thread safe concurrency behavior?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have been going through the java.util.concurrent package and trying to understand what the library provides to us . I came across `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and `ConcurrentHashMap` classes and trying to find how these clases achieve thread safety . For `CopyOnWriteArrayList` it is pretty much intuitive and they are implemented by making a fresh copy of the underlying array whenever there is a write operation . However I am not able to understand the bigger picture of how the `ConcurrentHashMap` achieves thread safety , providing concurrency at the same time ?

**Edit** : It would be enough if anyone can tell me the concepts that goes behind the implementation . Taking that in mind I can delve more into the source code and thus will help me in understanding it in a better way and structured manner.

Comment: Use the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java), Luke.

Comment: The source is pretty advanced stuff. I'm thinking he wants an explanation

Comment: @ Tichodroma I have gone through that source but it didnt help me . I am more interested in the concept behind how the concurrency and thread safety is achieved at the same time .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you really want to understand the way how to build concurrent hash map, i can advice to take a look into IBM article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08223/

Comment: I wonder why Brian Goetz doesn't write too often these days . All his articles provides tons of wisdom.